# zend debugger not recognize jquery post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-debugger

When posting forms using jquery post, the ZendDebugger lost its track.

For example, I have a file index.php wich submit button post to "formContent.php". something like:

```
//index.php 
 $("#formMiData").submit(function(){ 
      $.post("formContent.php", $("#formMiData").serialize(),
      function(data){
       $("#salidaAjax").html(data); 
      });  
      return false;

     });
```

I add a breakpoint to the begining of index.php and formContent.php. 
The debugger stops at the breakpoint in index.php, but not at the breakpoint at formContent.php.

Is this the way it works? o the debugger should find "formContent.php"?

I spent a lot of time trying to make the debugger work, but maybe is not suppose to work in this case...

Comment: It works sometimes, apparently, the problem have more to do with the debugger configuration. I think the debugger gets lost because i use apache redirection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the server configuration was not right in Eclipse. I had to configure the server and map the directories with the url.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this a bit more? I'm having the same problem as you where it only seems to work sometimes.